# Data parallelisation in Pytorch inference for multiple GPU

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

We are using data parallelisation for our project which is running on our server with 2 Nvidia gpu , for inference we are using Pytorch data parallelisation but the 2nd gpu is always in idle mode.

We are using the following code :

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
n_gpu = torch.cuda.device_count()

if torch.cuda.is_available():

    net.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_dir))
    if n_gpu> 1 :
        net = nn.DataParallel(net,device_ids = [0, 1])
    net.to(device)
```

Also see attached screenshot !

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky8Mk.png)

Comment: What happens if you try `torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(net, device_ids=[0, 1]` instead of nn.DataParallel ? [PyTorch doc source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-nn-ddp-instead)